# number of non-equivalent permutations of constant length of sequence of transpositions

Tags: permutations, symmetric-groups

We all know that the symmetric group $S_n$ could be viewed as a Coxeter group <$t_1,t_2,..,t_{n-1}|(t_i)^2=1 $>, where $t_i$ refers to transposition $(i,i+1)$. We define the length of a sequence of $\{t_1,t_2,..,t_{n-1}\}$ to be the number of bits in the sequence. For example, sequence $t_1t_2t_3t_4t_1$ has length 5 and sequence $t_1t_1t_2$ has length 3. Now suppose we have a sequence of length $k$, is there any theorem telling us how many different permutations are there among all these $(n-1)^k$ sequences?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I have "latexified" your question. As José Carlos santos said, you have to learn the basics of Latex/Mathjax for writing mathematical expressions on this site, and on many others : expressions must be enclosed between dollar signs, indices are obtained with underscores, etc...

Comment: Not sure there is a clearcut result, but have you attempted to write a "brute force" program examining all cases allowing to build a conjecture for some given $n,k$, for example $n=5,k=3$  $n=5,k=6$ and $n=5,k=9$ ?

Comment: A side reference [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/86107/305862) about the $(i,i+1)$ being generators of $S_n$.

Comment: @JeanMarie My apology for not using latex form and thank you very much for latexifying my question:) This is my first time using stack exchange. I haven't written a program on this question since I would like to know at first if anyone has already solved this question. Now it seems it would be interesting to start with some programming on this question:)

Comment: An interesting Edit in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2286481/305862)

Comment: Connected : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4278716/305862

Comment: @JeanMarie It is really an interesting theorem about the Coxeter length and the number of inversions :).  However, I think there is still a gap between the Coxeter length of a permutation and my question of the constant length permutation since in my question, $k$ is a constant length and the Coxeter length of the permutation could be smaller than $k$.

Comment: well, I think I got the solution for any $n \ge 3$, $k=2, 3$. The next step will be $k\ge 4$. :)

Comment: Well, if k is large enough, then the sequence will cover $\frac{n!}{2}$ of all the permutations(half the symmetric group). The proof is simple, as the number of odd permutations equals to the number of even permutations.